# Casting DATE/TIMESTAMP types to NUMERIC is prohibited in Hive 3.1.3

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, milliseconds

I am trying to cast dates from string format to numeric format in milliseconds trying to keep
also the .SSS part as I need to process data at the level of milliseconds duration. While in Hive 1.1.0 I am able to do that with the code below in the newer version it does not let me do that:

```
select current_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')*1000, cast((cast(date_format(cast(current_timestamp() as string),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as timestamp)) as double) * 1000 as time_milliseconds
```

Can you tell me a workaround to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract millisecond part from string and add to the (timestamp in seconds)*1000

```
select current_timestamp(),

--unix_timestamp returns seconds only    
unix_timestamp(current_timestamp())*1000, --without .SSS * 1000

unix_timestamp(current_timestamp())*1000 +
bigint(regexp_extract(string(current_timestamp()),'\\.(\\d+)$',1)) --with .SSS
```

Result:

```
2021-09-21 13:52:32.034  1632232352000  1632232352034
```

Explicit conversion to bigint and string may be not necessary.

One more method how you can get milliseconds part is to split string by dot and get element #1: `split(current_timestamp(),'\\.')[1]` instead of `regexp_extract(string(current_timestamp()),'\\.(\\d+)$',1)`:

```
select ts,  unix_timestamp(ts_splitted[0])*1000, unix_timestamp(ts_splitted[0]) * 1000 + ts_splitted[1]
from
(
select current_timestamp() ts, split(current_timestamp(),'\\.') ts_splitted
)s
```

Result:

```
2021-09-21 18:21:11.032   1632248471000  1632248471032
```

I prefer this method. Of course if you have timestamps with microseconds or nanoseconds, the logic should be adjusted accordingly based on the length of the fractional part.

Comment: great, thank you :)